# What should be the Http Server code for Validation Error happening in server?

Tags: validation, rest, http-status-codes, http-status-code-400

When an action is called by the client to server say POST/PUT, there would be some validations happening in the data that needs to be processed. But that data doesn't comes as a request, data would be fetched from DB (coz the endpoint clearly knows what it should do, so I dont tell the service what to update) and on top of that, validations would be performed.

So if any validation fails on such data, what should be the response code that should be returned?
Am sceptical to use 4XX codes, since those codes are reserved for the errors produced by client.

In my case, since client does not produce any error, what should be the response code for these kind of validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

If your service returns an error which is definetly not caused by the user's request data rather than from the data/state of the server, the service should respond with `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`. There is no specific *Internal Server Validation Error* status code in RFC2616/RFC7231, so I recommend to take the 'general' 500 status.

From RFC 7231:

`The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.`